# OpenFileDialog component in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, openfiledialog

I'm working on a VB project in Visual Studio 2017. It's a Blank App (Universal Windows) project. When trying to work with this type of app, it doesn't seem to have an OpenFileDialog like the Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) has. Is there a way to do one of two things:

1. Create a Windows Forms App that has the same look and feel as the Blank App (Universal Windows)
2. Add the OpenFileDialog option to the Blank App (Universal Windows)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't see any examples for Visual Basic though.

Comment: Surprising that MS doesn't have a VB example, but sometimes you have to do a little translation... see example in answers below.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing to get the same(ish) look was to just play around with some of the properties of the form and the buttons. This gave me the look that I was after. It wasn't exact, but I'll take it.

As for OpenFileDialog, I ended up using the following:

```
    Dim myStream As IO.Stream = Nothing
    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()

    ' Open file dialog parameters
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\"                    ' Default open location
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Executable Files (*.exe)|*.exe|All Files (*.*)|*.*"   
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                ' Insert code to read the stream here.
                Textbox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName

                ' Even though we're reading the entire path to the file, the file is going to be ignored and only the path will be saved.
                ' Mostly due to me lacking the ability to figure out how to open just the directory instead of a file. Resolution threadbelow.
                ' http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?570294-RESOLVED-textbox-openfiledialog-folder

                ' Setting the public variable so it can be used later
                Dim exepath As String
                exepath = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Me.txtExeLocation.Text)

            End If
        Catch Ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot read file from disk. Original error: " & Ex.Message)
        Finally
            ' Check this again, since we need to make sure we didn't throw an exception on open.
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                myStream.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a VB version of the MS example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker.

```
Imports Windows.Storage

Imports Windows.Storage.Pickers

Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
    Inherits Page

    Private Async Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim openPicker As New FileOpenPicker()
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg")
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg")
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png")

        Dim file As StorageFile = Await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync()

        If (file IsNot Nothing) Then
            Debug.WriteLine($"Picked File: {file.Name}")
        Else
            Debug.WriteLine("Operation Cancelled.")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```